# Grant select access on certain columns only in MySQL for phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-grant

I want to create a new user in my MySQL database that is able to select and update only certain columns of my table via phpmyadmin. I know this question has been asked several times here but I have a problem that was never mentioned before.

I use this command to give the user access to select two rows in the table:

```
GRANT SELECT (id,name) ON db.table TO 'user'@'%'
```

When I login with this user at phpmyadmin and want to display the table (i.e. only the columns id and name) it gives me following error message:

```
#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'table'
```

If I grant select on the table it works but then the user can see the whole table.
Can anybody please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I also tried it with a view and that worked perfectly. The problem was, when I used the search function of phpmyadmin, I was not able to do any changes to the search results. The error messsage said that there was no 'unique' key defined, but the view contained the primary key column and another column that was defined as unique.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check if 'user'@'localhost' has GRANT privileges that are overriding the 'user'@'%'.

Try these commands:

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';
and
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%';

Then compare the privileges shown.